# Is it safe for a subprocess opened with Popen to keep writing to a file handle after the parent python program finishes?

Tags: python, subprocess

The following code works:

test.py

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['bash', 'test.sh'], stdout=open("output.txt", "w"))
```

test.sh

```
sleep 10
echo "hello world"
```

results

```
[hastings@$Hastingss-Air ~/sample_project]$ python test.py
[hastings@$Hastingss-Air ~/sample_project]$ cat output.txt
[hastings@$Hastingss-Air ~/sample_project]$ cat output.txt
hello world
```

with the two cat calls demonstrating that yes, "hello (yawn) world" is only written after the parent has already returned control to the shell. Is this a documented feature that I can rely on?

Leaving a file handle dangling feels wrong, but the standard `with open()` approach definitely doesn't work since it closes the file before the subprocess is done.

Comment: It should work the same using `with`. A file isn't really closed until all processes that have references to it close it. The subprocess keeps the file open.